# How to pause a timer in SpriteKit by using AppDelegate, Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, appdelegate

I am making a iPhone game and try to pause the game when the game is interrupted, such as incoming phone call. I have timers using in my project and don't know how to access them from AppDelegate. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, we are not here to write your code. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work for you and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I answered your question. I had the same problem as you. You can access your timer in GameScene if you do what I said. Tap on the green check mark if my answer helps you. @Smile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did in my game. Just define the timer variable outside the GameScene Class instead of inside it.

```
var timer = NSTimer() //Define my timer outside my gamescene class so I could access it in App Delegate

class GameScene: SKScene {



}
```

Comment: This was very useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me, is to create a new Swift file called Shared.swift or such and declare any variables and constants that I need to be able to use in other scenes.

So, create a file called Shared.swift.

In Shared, move the declaration of your timer into it. You don't need to declare Shared as a class or struct, here's what Shared should look like:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

//All three aren't necessary for just a timer, but will save time later if you decide to declare other things here

//Now, MOVE the declaration of your timer here

let timer: NSTimer?
```

That's it, just access it in AppDelegate like you declared it there.

Comment: Looks great, I will try! base on the answers I googled, many people suggest using NSNotificationcenter. I will try both and see which works better.

Answer (score 0):

You can create shared a var on AppDelegate and when your method by NSTimer is called, you check if the var is valid before leaving their following method, example:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var isGameOver:Bool = false
    //.....
}
```

On GameScene

```
// MARK: Methods
func addBall(timer:NSTimer?){

    if (appDelegate.isGameOver) {
         return
    }

    //.....
    // all logic here...
}
```

That way you control your timers just using flags, I make this in my games and work for me.